# Lib for generating documentation of svelte components

Tags: svelte

does anybody knows if there is a standardized way to document svelte components and a lib which would generate a markdown documentation?

I've found just this https://www.npmjs.com/package/sveltedoc-parser which looks kinda dead by now. And it generates just a JSON with bunch of data and I have to create the markdown documentation on my onw from it.